# Replace NULL with empty string in backend or frontend?

Tags: sql, mariadb

A lot of my database tables contains `NULL` values. I have no reason to store `NULL` values, that's just how the data I imported looked like. Having "NULL" in my HTML tables when I show the data to my users looks weird though. Should I change `NULL` to empty strings in my database, or should I replace "NULL" with "" in the frontend when I display the data with JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't change NULLs in the database. Your 2nd option: *replace "NULL" with "" in the frontend* is what you should do.

Comment: @forpas Okay! Thank you. Do you know of a simple way of doing that? I'm using jQuery to loop through the rows of retrived data with `each()` and then appending the data in cells of a HTML table.

Comment: I can't help you with jQuery. If you edit your question or post another question related to that I'm sure you will get the proper solution.

Comment: A third option is to use something like `COALESCE(col,'')` in the query, to change the null's in the resultset to empty strings.  But most would argue that this is a representation problem, hence be solved in the presentation layer.

Comment: Is the value `NULL`, the SQL "constant", or is it `'NULL'`, a string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's the SQL "constant".

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`